AFforms addon of CIVICRM the form is getting submitted in the backend but in the frontend it showing error your form data is not submitted
when trying to submit form created with aaform addon it is getting submitted in the backend but in the frontend it's showing error, i can also see entries in dashboard


Form Settings



Error Screenshot's



Hi. Could you share the settings for the form and the relevant entities in use? It may be missing something or potentially permission related.

@ RebeccaTregenna pls find the below screenshots

hi, anyone please help me to resolve this issue

If you are using the 'user based' permission on the 'Individual' tab it may be worth trying with 'Form Based'

okay, will check the permission and try with form based

hi @RebeccaTregenna i tried changing to form based permission, the form data is storing in database, i can see entries in dashboard, but in the frontend after submitting the form now i am getting new error in alert box

1)sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved
2)sorry an error occurred and your request was not completed                                                  when i check by inspecting element i can see one error in browser console i.e  https://domain/page-name/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Fapi4%2FAfform%2Fsubmit and when i open that link it showing {"error_code":405,"error_message":"SECURITY: All requests that modify the database must be http POST, not GET."}

Please any one can help me to resolve this
